# Samsung Galaxy Tab2 10.1 not supported on google play

Tags: android

I have this issue on Google play. It states the tab on subject is not supported due to file manifest permission.

Those are the permissions and hardware required:

```
android.permission.INTERNET, 
android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, 
android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, 
android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS, 
android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE, 
android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, 
android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

android.hardware.location, 
android.hardware.location.gps, 
android.hardware.location.network, 
android.hardware.touchscreen
```

as asked this is the manifest

```
<supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" 
  android:smallScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" 
  android:largeScreens="true" android:resizeable="true" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

I don't see anything 'unsupported', can anyone help me?

Thank you

Comment: Could u post the AndroidManifest.xml? Or the "Uses Feature" item?

Comment: not yet I added AndroidManifest.xml

Answer (score 2):

Please add the below code in your `Manifest` file under `<manifest>` tag:

```
 <supports-screens android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true" android:smallScreens="true"
    android:resizeable="true" android:anyDensity="true" />
```

This `support` tag states that your application is supported for all screen sizes.

Comment: did u find solution from my answer? if so, pls Accept and UPVOTE my answer